What tag for studies of beauty, aesthetics, etc.?
We've had a fair few questions about perception of beauty or aesthetic judgements?

Why do we prefer visually aligned objects?
Is Golden Ratio's association with perceived beauty a myth?
Why do humans prefer symmetrical arrangement of objects?

What's a good tag for this?
UPDATE: I also note that we have the physical-attraction tag.

I would propose that most of those physical attraction questions would be better tagged sexual-attraction

If there is a proper scientific term in the field of psychology/psychiatry/neuroscience/cognitive science, clearly that should be used. If anyone knows of such a term, please answer this question with it!
I am unaware of a specific scientific term for this, so in the absence of one I pospose we use aesthetics

Wikipedia defines Aesthetics as: a branch of philosophy dealing with the nature of beauty, art, and taste, with the creation and appreciation of beauty
While this is a site about science and not philosophy, the rest of that definition is accurate.
The Wikipedia article does mention some references to psychology.
There is a professional journal called Psychology of Aesthetics, Creativity, and the Arts® so this term has at least 8some* usage in the field of psychology
I can't think of a better term after googling a number of posibilities.


I think aesthetics is about as close as we'll get

I've retagged the questions with "aesthetics" rather than "beauty"
